# Connecting Rails backend with Angular frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, resources, jbuilder

I'm new to Angular, and I'd really appreciate some help in connecting my
Rails backend with my Angular frontend.

In my `Angular controller`, I want to retrieve `JSON` data from my `Rails` backend.  Using, `jbuilder`, I am able to retrieve JSON from this URL: `http://localhost:3000/assessments/1.json`.  The JSON is: `{"id":1,"course_id":1,"part_id":1,"lesson_id":1,"type_of":"Quiz"}`.  This seems okay backend-wise.  But, when I try to retrieve that JSON in my Angular controller...

```
app.controller('ThisController', [
'$scope',
'$resource',
function($scope, $resource){
  var Assess = $resource("/assessments/:id.json", {id: "@id", format: 'json'});
  console.log(Assess);
  console.log(Assess.get());

  Assess.get(function(callbackdata){
      //function is called on success
      console.log(callbackdata);
    }
  );

  $scope.findType = function() {
    $resolved = true;
    $scope.description = 'This is a ' + Assess.type_of + '!';
  };

}]);
```

...I get this in my `console.log`...

1. `function Resource(value)`
2. `Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false}`
3. `Resource {0: "<", 1: "!", 2: "D", 3: "O", 4: "C", 5: "T", 6: "Y", 7: "P", 8: "E", 9: " ", 10: "h", 11: "t", 12: "m", 13: "l",...`

The third console.log output is individual string characters broken up from my `layout/application.html.erb` file!

In my Angular view...

```
<div>
  <h3>Type:</h3>
    <button ng-click='findType()'>Find Type</button>
  <hr>
  {{description}}
</div>
```

... I get, `This is a undefined!` when I call the function for `'findType()'`... for `{{description}}`.

If anyone can tell me where I've gone wrong with `$resource`, I'd sure appreciate it.  PS: I'm set up with the `ngResource` dependency, so that's not an issue.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check what angular requests and it's response in the Network tab in Chrome Inspector. Also check Rails' log to see if the format is processed correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Should the Rails' log show me the .json url?  I can't seem to find that in my log--although I did see my `layout/application.html.erb` file there.  My `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` file has... `ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do; wrap_parameters format [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters); end`...only.  Could that be a factor here.

Comment: It should say something like `Processing AssignmentsController#show as JSON`. Check the that correct action is called and if the parameters are correct.